# Not able to redirect from controller to gsp in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am new to grails,I am trying to redirect to render a gsp after doing some processing with my model object in controller but every time i am getting following error:

```
Line | Method
->> 195 | doFilter in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    63 | doFilter in AbstractFilter.java
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I am able to redirect to another gsp if i dont process my domain(setProperties method) i.e if I remove the for loop.

Following is my controller code:

```
def receiveClient() {
        PartyClient partyClientInstance=PartyClient.get(params.client1Id)
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            if(key.endsWith("Checked")){
                setProperties(key,partyClientInstance)
            }
        }
        render (view: "receiveClient",model: [partyClientInstance: partyClientInstance])
    }

def setProperties(String key,PartyClient partyClient){
    int i =key.indexOf("Checked");
    String property=key.substring(0, i);

    if(property.equals("firstName")){
        partyClient.setFirstName(params[key])
    }else if(property.equals("lastName")){
        partyClient.setLastName(params[key])
    }else if(property.equals("middleName")){
        partyClient.setMiddleName(params[key])
    }else if(property.equals("title")){
        partyClient.setTitle(params[key])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include more stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: try to rename your method `setProperties()` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a command object to present the *receiveClient* view.

By the way the error message that you pasted may not contain all the relevant information, your stacktrace is rather small...

- Once you get your *partyClientInstance*, copy it inside a command matching the domain properties.
- If your view has a form to save the model, then in the relevant action, copy the command to the model and persist the data if needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try `grails-debug run-app` and use an IDE to add breakpoints. I am little skeptical about the usage of `PartyClient` in `setProperties()`. I hope debugging would help. Debug port by default is `5005`.